# Accurev: How can I see new folders created in a parent stream inside a workspace?

Tags: new-operator, directory, accurev

I've created a new folder (with files and sub-folders) in a workspace. I then promoted them all into a parent stream (and even to the grandparent one). However I cannot see them in another workspace stemming from that parent stream. It does not appear in Exclude/Include mode either.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 1):

Michael - you'll need to 'update' the other workspace.   That (older) workspace only has visibility to the transactional state of its backing streams as of its last update... part of the TimeSafe architecture.

HTH _ dave

Comment: Naturally, update was the first thing I tried to do. This did not help of course. Notice, that this "other" workspace was created using Pick & Choose method. So there are more folders that are invisible. But of course they are all there when I swith to Include/Exclude mode, except for this new folder I am talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Michael, it may require some debugging through support, but there's no logical reason for that content to not appear once you update.  It's possible the workspace is out of sync.  From a command-line, please perform the following in the P&C workspace:

- accurev stat -m  (This checks for modified files in progress. If any exist, Keep them)
- accurev update -9  (This forces the workspace to update to the current transactional level)
- accurev pop -O -R .  (This replaces the content of the workspace)

At this point, after the update -9, you should be able to turn on Include/Exclude and see the new content.  If not, I'd suggest you log a Support case with AccuRev.

Regards,
~James